# Cannot read file of a supplementary group

Tags: linux, file-permissions, qnx

I have two groups manually created in /etc/group:

```
file-owner:x:300:user
user:x:400:
```

I have a configuration file, owned by the user/group `file-owner`. I don't want other users to read it.

```
 ls -l /tmp/my-configs.txt         
 -r--r-----   1   file-owner   file-owner   1054552  Jun 11  12:22  /tmp/my-configs.txt
```

I run a process with id `user:user` but I cannot read the configuration file owned by `file-owner`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you verify that `user` is part of the `file-owner` group with the `groups` command? Just making sure since you have to log out and back in for group changes to take effect.

Comment: @JohnMoon the result of `id user`: `uid=400(user) gid=400(user) groups=400(user),300(file-owner)`

Comment: I see you're using QNX? Does the file system you're using include any special ACLs outside the POSIX permission scheme? http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide/topic/files_acls.html